# create a scheduled task with execution date made by the administrator in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Already create scheduled tasks in laravel, now how can I pass parameters from the controller this is possible?

My problem is this:
an administrator from the view creates a meeting event with start and end date and in the controller a scheduled task is also created for the final day of the meeting.

This scheduled task will be executed on the final day of the meeting and will be passed the parameters of: id of the event and the final date of the event at the moment of its creation

How could I do this and create it from a controller?
so every time the admin creates an event with start and end date the scheduled task is also created and executed on the final date of the event

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataBase to store the tasks with the terget date to exeute them.
Then, create scheduled task in App\Console\Kernel ([see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#defining-schedules) how to define it) that every day reads from the DataBase all the tasks for this date and executes them.